# Updating attributes with search bar in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to dynamically render and update views when string contains substring with addition of attribute.
 I need to use JavaScript object like this: `var ObjectArray =[{"title:"Great Title"},{"title":"Interesting Title"},{"title":"Boring Title"}];`

This is what i found but it uses react kind of object and renders only fitting matches.

```js
let contacts = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Sherlock',
  phone: '221 221 221'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Watson',
  phone: '332 333 331'
}]

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Contact List</h2>
        <br />
        <ContactList contacts={this.props.contacts} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
class Contact extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li>{this.props.contact.name} {this.props.contact.phone}</li>
    )
  }
}
class ContactList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      search: ''
    };
  }
  updateSearch(event) {
    this.setState({
      search: event.target.value.substr(0, 10)
    });
  }
  render() {
    let filteredContacts = this.props.contacts.filter(
      (contact) => {
        return contact.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase());
      }
    );
    console.log(filteredContacts);
    return (
      <div>
        <input className="text" type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)} />
        <hr />
        <ul>
        {filteredContacts.map((contact) => {
          return <Contact contact={contact} key={contact.id} />
        })}
        </ul>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App contacts={contacts} />, document.getElementById('container'));

ReactDOM.render(
  <FilterableProductTable products={PRODUCTS} />,
   document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

I had my attempts at changing this code but it used all static solutions which did not update.

This is a concept i had:

```js
var ObjectArray =[{"title":"Great Title"},{"title":"Interesting Title"},{"title":"Boring Title"}];
var BoolArray = Array(ObjectArray.length).fill(false);
class App extends React.Component {

 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      search: ''
    };
  }
  updateSearch(event) {
    this.setState({
      search: event.target.value.substr(0, 10)
    });
  }
  render() {
      return(
      <input className="text" type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)} />
      )
      {ObjectArray.map((obj, index) => {
        return(
          <h1 className={BoolArray[index] ? 'red' : 'blue'}>{obj.title}</h1>
        )
      }
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>
   document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.red{
  color : red;
}
.blue{
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
 <div id="root">
```

Comment: Your problems are not clear, Try to explain, what do you want? what did you try so far? and what problem did you get?

Comment: I am trying to set className attribute to blue/red based on matches of substrings in strings. If string contain substring i would like className attribute to change to red.

Comment: I have tried solution using if statments but it did not work very well.

Comment: I need to render all three elements but with different className based on search matches.

Answer (score 0):

`yes` is expected to be an object map but is not defined, that will cause issues.

```
 return(
  <input className="text" type="text" value={this.state.search} onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)} />
  )
```

so, you return that expression and then continue under it? that's dead code because function has exited.

react can only *currently* return 1 root level element. if you need to return more, you have to wrap into an element.

so

```
render(){
  return <div>
    <input ... />
    {something.map(el => <h1>{el.title}</h1>)}
  </div>
}
```

Comment: "yes" arrray was supposed to be BoolArray but i forgot to change it.

Comment: BoolArray was supposed to gather values of matches.

Comment: found a pic of OP: https://i.redd.it/gnrjqxgm4tez.gif - dev by copy/paste w/o an understanding is probably not going to be easy :)

Comment: If title of the string is containing substring it is supposed to change value from false to true and based on that tell  {ObjectArray.map((obj, index) => { to render it with attribute red.

Comment: I just spend a lot of time on it and can not even make a proper example of what i meant..